# How to subtract a specific number from all the documents in original DB

Tags: mongodb

as my title as, I want to subtract a `specificNumber` lets say `200` from all my documents where `someAttribute` has a value greater than `specificNumber` in mongoDB
here is my schema.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Employee = new Schema({
    first_name: { type: String },
    last_name: { type: String },
    title: { type: String },
    email: { type: String },
    gender: { type: String },
    location: { type: String },
    phone: { type: String },
    branch: { type: String },
    department: { type: String },
    positionX: { type: Number },
    positionY: { type: Number }
},
    { collection: 'Employees' });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Employees', Employee)
```

I searched the mongoDB forum, they were using the `aggregation` method, but the problem with that is, it just returns the values, doesn't modify the array.
How do I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Model.updateMany`. Using `$gt` in your query & `$inc` in the update. You can use negative values in the `$inc` operator.

```
const updatedDocuments = await Employee.updateMany(
            { [someAttribute]: { $gt: someNumber } },
            { $inc: { [someAttribute]: -someNumber } }
        );
```